# Issues with SchemaSpy

Tags: schema, schema-builder

I am facing issues with Schemaspy when trying to connect with Production org. Below is the build.xml I am using -

```
<project default="document">

  <property name="sf.username" value="I PUT THE USERNAME"/>
  <property name="sf.password" value="I PUT PASSWORD AND SECURITY TOKEN"/>

  <target name="document">
      <echo message="Generating SchemaSpy documentation (requires Graphviz to be installed to produce diagrams)"/>
      <delete dir="doc" failonerror="false"/>
      <java classname="net.sourceforge.schemaspy.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true">
          <arg line="-t schemaspy/force"/>
          <arg line="-db Claims"/>
          <arg line="-un ${sf.username}"/>
          <arg line="-pw ${sf.password}"/>
          <arg line="-o doc"/>
          <arg line="-font Arial"/>
          <arg line="-fontsize 8"/>
          <arg line="-hq"/>
          <arg line="-norows"/>
          <arg line='-desc "Extracted from Consumer Org r${env.SVN_REVISION} on Force.com"'/>
          <arg line="-u fake"/>
          <arg line="-p fake"/>
          <arg line="-host fake"/>
          <arg line="-connprops url\=https://<I PUT THE DOMAIN>.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/22.0"/>
          <classpath>
               <fileset dir="schemaspy" includes="*.jar"/>
          </classpath>
      </java>
  </target>

</project>
```

This is the error I am getting -

```
Sudiptas-MacBook-Pro:runSchemaSpy sudiptadeb$ ant
Buildfile: /Users/sudiptadeb/Documents/Sudipta Deb/Salesforce/runSchemaSpy/build.xml

document:
     [echo] Generating SchemaSpy documentation (requires Graphviz to be installed to produce diagrams)
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/sudiptadeb/Documents/Sudipta Deb/Salesforce/runSchemaSpy/doc
     [java] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
     [java]     at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendExpandedReplacement(Matcher.java:1068)
     [java]     at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:998)
     [java]     at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:1181)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2125)
     [java]     at net.sourceforge.schemaspy.util.ConnectionURLBuilder.buildUrl(ConnectionURLBuilder.java:72)
     [java]     at net.sourceforge.schemaspy.util.ConnectionURLBuilder.<init>(ConnectionURLBuilder.java:50)
     [java]     at net.sourceforge.schemaspy.SchemaAnalyzer.analyze(SchemaAnalyzer.java:139)
     [java]     at net.sourceforge.schemaspy.Main.main(Main.java:42)

BUILD FAILED
/Users/sudiptadeb/Documents/Sudipta Deb/Salesforce/runSchemaSpy/build.xml:12: Java returned: 1
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

It's a good few years since I wrote and used this (assuming you are using [force-metadata-jdbc-driver](https://code.google.com/archive/p/force-metadata-jdbc-driver/) here), but looking at the stacktrace, you need more escaping in the `url` that is buried in the `connprops`. Add more backslashes...

That string passes through regular expression logic and such logic scans for special characters. Something more like this should work:

```
url\=https:\/\/abc\.my\.salesforce\.com\/services\/Soap\/u\/22\.0
```

The reason for this craziness is that the Salesforce-specific logic is slotted into an existing tool (the wonderful SchemaSpy) as if it were a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) and so extra information has to be sneaked past the SchemaSpy command-line interface.

Comment: I changed it to <arg line="-connprops url\=https:\/\/abc\.my\.salesforce\.com\/services\/Soap\/u\/22\.0"/>, but still the same problem.  This is what I have in force.properties -                               
description=Force
driver=com.claimvantage.force.jdbc.ForceMetaDataDriver
connectionSpec=jdbc:gunpla:force:<un>:<pw>

Comment: @SudiptaDeb FYI, this has recently moved to https://github.com/claimvantage/force-metadata-jdbc-driver; the docs are a little better there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to figure it out. Having $ in the password was creating the problem. I have changed the password by removing $ and it is working fine for me now. Learned something new.